# PhpStorm - xdebug issues

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've read a few blogs & tried replicating the setup to get xdebug working with PhpStorm but not able to. Infact I'm unable to get it working with Netbeans too.

The setup I have is as below

1) Windows 7 machine (Host OS) where I've installed PhpStorm and there is a local project directory for PhpStorm as I see form the project properties.

2) The code is deployed to a Linux environment (CentOS) hosting Apache, MySQL & PHP.

3) I'd like to be able click the option "Debug project" & be able to debug the code hosted on the virtual machine (Linux).

I've set up xdebug on the linux environment, Here's the errors that I'm seeing when I run the project in debug mode. Could I seek some advice please?

```
sftp://vcrt@192.168.1.10:22/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.8 /home/vcrt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --no-configuration /var/www/projectlive
Testing started at 12:36 PM ...
bash: line 0: cd: C:/Users/<<user>>/PhpstormProjects: No such file or directory
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Process finished with exit code 1
Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php)
```

Comment: So far I only see PHP issues (bad `php.ini` config).

Comment: Hi, have you tried `Run -> Webserver debug validation` ?

Comment: thanks Asped & LazyOne. I tried with netbeans installed on linux directly. Xdebug works from there. So for now, I'll park this one. Thank you heaps.

Comment: Two potential issues are at play here: xdebug and phpunit.  Based on the output you provided, it seems like phpunit isn't installed properly on your Linux machine, thus leading to the acute problem you're encountering.

To better identify and resolve your potential *xdebug* issues, please try to debug a simple PHP script, rather than attempting to debug a unit test.